# UTF-8 BOM displaying symbols instead of text

Tags: text, encoding

Looks like this:

[image]

New to coding etc. and I'm trying to create a small mod for a game called Megaton Rainfall, I'm 90% sure the code I want to change/mod is in my scripts.fcm file but I can't figure out how to change it to readable text. I've switched the encoding to every different kind and it still remains unreadable. Please help if there is a way :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than opening in Notepad++ try opening in another text editor such as [Vim](http://www.vim.org/), [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) or Notepad.  This should then be "readable text"